# Azure Speech SDK Intent recognition Error on Ubuntu MATE ARM32

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core, azure-speech

I am trying to do basic intent recognition using the Speech SDK on Ubuntu MATE ARM32 (on a Raspberry Pi). The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/releasenotes) say the version 1.11 should work but I am getting the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ApplicationException: Exception with an error code: 0x8 (SPXERR_FILE_OPEN_FAILED)
   at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.SpxExceptionThrower.ThrowIfFail(IntPtr hr)
   at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.KeywordRecognitionModel.FromFile(String fileName)
   at SmartHomeVoice.Services.ListeningService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in E:\Efraim's stuff\SmartHomeVoice\SmartHomeVoice\Services\ListeningService.cs:line 142
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at SmartHomeVoice.Program.Main() in E:\Efraim's stuff\SmartHomeVoice\SmartHomeVoice\Program.cs:line 19
Aborted
```

I am using C# and .Net Core 3.1, and I have a webcam plugged into the Pi which I set to be the default audio input through the GUI.
Ubuntu version is 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/594). The problem was that I didn't supply an absolute path for the keyword table file.

Comment: You are encouraged to answer your own questions and accept the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer